# Using JSON, how do I UPDATE/POST a new message in a discussion of a Rally artifact?

Tags: rest, rally

This syntax does not work:

Example URL: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Defect/ObjectID?key=key

```
{ "Defect":
{
Discussion":
{
"Text": "some text"
} 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conversation post has to be created with a reference to the artifact.

Here is a POST URL format:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/ConversationPost/create?key=abc123...
```

In this example 777 is ObjectID of a defect on which you want to create a conversation post. Here is the Request Body:

```
{
"ConversationPost": {
"Artifact": "/defect/777",
"Text":"some text"
}
}
```